# How to show option in ngx-contextmenu conditionally?

Tags: angular, contextmenu

I implemented context menu in my Angular 6 project using `ngx-contextmenu`. I'd like to show some option in this menu only if selected object has defined specified attribute. For example - in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-contextmenu-example-dpoqzq) how can I show "Say hi!" option only if the item has defined `otherProperty`?

I see that `<ng-template *ngIf="$event.item.otherProperty"` cannot be used in `right-click.component.html". Should I define two components extending`RightClickComponent`and select the proper one in`AppComponent.onContextMenu()`?

Comment: Try using your `*ngIf` on a new selector under the desired `<ng-template`>. It should work.

Comment: @TheUnreal: Yes, `*ngIf` works here, but if condition is false then there is empty space in the context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should better read [documentation](https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu) next time. ;) `ngx-contextmenu` has implemented possibility of showing/hiding specific items. It can be done by `visible` input parameter, e.g;

HTML template:

```
<ng-template [visible]="showOption" contextMenuItem let-item>
   Say hi!
</ng-template>
```

component.ts file:

```
showOption(item: any) {
    return 'otherProperty' in item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @**trivelt**'s answer, if you have some variables in your component that you want to use in your conditional method (i.e: some @Input that you receive from a parent component), the usage of a code like:

```
showOption(item: any) {
return 'otherProperty' in item;
}
```

won't work and you will get an error.
The right way of usage in this case is something like this:

```
public outsideValue = "something"
public showOption = (item: any): boolean => {
  return item.type === this.outsideValue;
}
```